# Facing issue while accessing component using component-link in the embedded schema

Tags: dd4t

I am trying to follow this question https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/12237/1556

In the Model for a "Container" Component, we have:

All the models contain Getter and Setter for it's field

```
@ViewModel(viewModelNames = {"*****"},
rootElementNames = "Container", setComponentObject = true)

public class Container extends TridionViewModelBase{

@ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "linkedComponentAndKeywords")
private List<XmbLinkedComponentAndKeywords> linkedComponentAndKeywords;  //Embedded schema field

}
```

In the Model for the ComponentAndKeywords Embedded Schema (used in the Container), we have:

```
public class XmbLinkedComponentAndKeywords extends TridionViewModelBase{

@ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "linkedComponent")
private LinkedComponent linkedComponent;   //component link

}
```

For the  "LinkedComponent," we have:

```
public class LinkedComponent extends TridionViewModelBase{

@ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "heading")
private String heading;

@ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "description")
private String description;

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public void setHeading(String heading) {
    this.heading = heading;
}

}
```

Does this seem like the right approach for DD4T Java (version 1)?

In the JSP View, we have

```
<jsp:useBean id="Container" type="com.***.web.models.Container" scope="request" />

<c:forEach var="linkedComponentAndKeywords" items="${Container.linkedComponentAndKeywords}" varStatus="Count">
    <c:out value="${linkedComponentAndKeywords.linkedComponent.heading}" />
    <c:out value="${linkedComponentAndKeywords.linkedComponent.description}" />
</c:forEach>
```

**What am i missing in this code? How can i fix this?**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field
>   com.***.web.models.LinkedComponent.heading to
>   org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentImpl  at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)  at
>   org.dd4t.databind.builder.AbstractModelConverter.setComponentOnField(AbstractModelConverter.java:67)
>     at
>   org.dd4t.databind.builder.AbstractModelConverter.setFieldValue(AbstractModelConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonModelConverter.deserializeGeneric(JsonModelConverter.java:276)
>     at
>   org.dd4t.databind.builder.json.JsonModelConverter.buildField(JsonModelConverter.java:194)

Comment: FYI, I deleted my original question as Neetesh's question provides a better example of what we're trying to do.

Comment: Are you using dd4t-1 with the databind framework?

Comment: Hi Raimond, thanks for your response! yes we are using dd4t-1.0 , can you please help me out , how do i check whether it is with databind framework or not ?

Comment: Hi - dd4t-1 cannot handle the databind framework! You'd have to upgrade to dd4t-2!

Answer (score 1):

We have made workaround for this problem of accessing attribute of LinkedComponent from JSON returns from tridion cms.

**I don't know, if it is a proper solution but it is working for us**

```
public class LinkedComponent extends TridionViewModelBase{

    @ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "heading")
    private ComponentImpl heading;
    @ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "description")
    private ComponentImpl description;

    public ComponentImpl getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    public void setHeading(ComponentImpl heading) {
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public ComponentImpl getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(ComponentImpl description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String get_heading() {
        return heading.getContent().get("heading").getValues().get(0).toString();
    }

    public String get_description() {
        return description.getContent().get("description").getValues().get(0).toString();
    }

}
```

and on the jsp view side it works as by calling **linkedComponent._heading** and **linkedComponent._description**

```
<jsp:useBean id="Container" type="com.***.web.models.Container" scope="request" />

<c:forEach var="linkedComponentAndKeywords" items="${Container.linkedComponentAndKeywords}" varStatus="Count">
    <c:out value="${linkedComponentAndKeywords.linkedComponent._heading}" />
    <c:out value="${linkedComponentAndKeywords.linkedComponent._description}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field 
com.***.web.models.LinkedComponent.heading to   
org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentImpl
```

means that you have an embedded or linked component in the **heading** field and not a **String**. This means that the deserializer cannot set the property correctly.

Neetesh has given the proper answer, although in terms of code cleanliness, I'd do the following:

```
public class LinkedComponent extends TridionViewModelBase{

    @ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "heading")
    private Component heading;
    @ViewModelProperty(entityFieldName = "description")
    private Component description;

    public Component getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    public void setHeading(Component heading) {
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public Component getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(Component description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getHeading() {
        // TODO: check for nulls
        return heading.getContent().get("heading").getValues().get(0).toString();
    }

    public String getDescription() {
    // TODO: check for nulls
        return description.getContent().get("description").getValues().get(0).toString();
    }
}
```

If you just want String values in for instance the heading or description fields, you will have to change your content model accordingly and not use either embedded components or linked components.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll give a try and let you know. :)

Comment: Let me know if you encounter issues :)

Comment: Hi Raimond, sorry for late response, i tried your suggestion on my code, that is working fine, Thanks for the same.... :)

Answer (score 0):

In your stacktrace you have the following snippet:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.***.web.models.LinkedComponent.heading to org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentImpl at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)

The last line in this snippet hints that you're trying to access a property without proper access modifiers, e.g. a privately declared properly trying to be accessed as if it was public perhaps?

Here is what the Oracle docs say on it:

An IllegalAccessException may be thrown if an attempt is made to get or set the value of a private or otherwise inaccessible field or to set the value of a final field (regardless of its access modifiers).
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTrouble.html

So check again your getters and setters. You may have a typo where the variable name doesn't match its property names.

It's also possible that you have the getter, but are missing a setter. I believe even if you don't need setters in some cases, the reflection API at the lower levels of the framework does.

Comment: Can you share them?  Also, look around com.***.web.models.LinkedComponent.heading. Is "heading" a String type or an embedded class?

Comment: Thanks Nickoli for your response !!!

getter and setter are declared as public and they are generated through IDE .

I can render the component which is component-linked separately , but when i was trying to render the same component using embedded schema i am getting that exception !!

is there some issue with embedded schema?

Comment: heading is String type

Comment: i have updated question as you asked !!!